# How to split a Mysql string data field value (PHP) and export results into XML

Tags: php, mysql, xml, string, split

How to split a Mysql string data field value and export results into XML:

(The data input/stored is: Dishwasher Fridge; Freezer Gas; Cooker ;)

the actual current working code is:

```
if ($row->appliances){
$appliances = str_replace(";", " ",$row->appliances )."";
} else {
$appliances = "";
```

That currently produces an XML output of:

```
<.appliances.>Dishwasher Fridge Freezer Gas Cooker<./appliances.>
```

The required outcome XML outcome is:

```
.<.appliance1>Dishwasher<./appliance1>

.<.appliance2>Fridge Freezer<./appliance2>

.<.appliance3>Gas Cooker<./appliance3>
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `str_replace` use `explode` -

```
if ($row->appliances){
    $appliances = explode(";", $row->appliances ); // $appliances is now an array
    for($i = 0; $i < count($appliances) - 1; $i++) { // loop through the array
        // format your XML here, $appliances[$i] will be the current appliance
    }
} else {
    $appliances = "";
}
```